# Asserting a call to a public method on the same mock instance

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, fakeiteasy

I have the following test

```
[Test]
public void Attack_TargetWith3Damage_CausesAttackerToDeal3DamageToTarget()
{
    var realAttacker = CreateCreature(damage: 3);
    var wrappedAttacker = A.Fake<ICreature>(x => x.Wrapping(realAttacker));
    var target = A.Fake<ICreature>();
    wrappedAttacker.Attack(target);
    A.CallTo(() => wrappedAttacker.DealDamage(target, 3)).MustHaveHappened();
}
```

The problem is that the call to `DealDamage` from the `Attack` method isn't being registered, because inside the method, `this` is `realAttacker` not `wrappedAttacker` attacker hence the method call isn't being intercepted.

How can I test this assertion?  Can this be done with FakeItEasy?  Does a different mocking framework allow me to test this?

Comment: This is a problem I experienced with NSubstitute as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ckittel for pointing me to this answer.  For this to work, the `Creature` class needs to have a parameterless constructor, and the methods need to be virtual.

The one extra thing with FakeItEasy seems that you have to tell it to call base method, otherwise conceptually it's the same, just different syntax.

```
[Test]
public void Attack_TargetWith3Damage_CausesAttackerToDeal3DamageToTarget()
{
    var attacker = A.Fake<Creature>();
    A.CallTo(attacker).CallsBaseMethod(); //Otherwise it seems all calls are no-ops.
    attacker.Stats.Damage = 3;

    var target = A.Fake<ICreature>();
    attacker.Attack(target);
    A.CallTo(() => attacker.DealDamage(target, 3)).MustHaveHappened();
}
```

Comment: FWIW, as far as the constructor params goes, moq doesn't have this limitation.  I could have provided constructor args if necessary, I just didn't in my answer to keep it simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can get pretty close to what you are after using [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) for your mocking framework.

Take this as an example:

```
public interface ICreature { ... }

public class Creature : ICreature
{
    ... 

    public void Attack(ICreature creature)
    {
        DealDamage(creature, 3); // Hard-coded 3 to simplify example only
    }

    public virtual void DealDamage(ICreature target, int damage) { ... }
}

.... Test ....
var wrappedAttacker = new Mock<Creature>();
var mockTarget = new Mock<ICreature>();

wrappedAttacker.Object.Attack(mockTarget.Object);

wrappedAttacker.Verify(x => x.DealDamage(mockTarget.Object, 3), Times.Once());
```

In this case I'm "wrapping" the a `Creature` *instance* in a mock for the attacker role and creating a `ICreature` mock for the target role.  I then call the `Attack` method from the attacker; verifying that the same attacker's `DealDamage` was called (with the correct target and 3 damage), exactly one time.

What makes this verification possible in Moq is that the `DealDamage` function is marked `virtual`.  This may be a deal-breaker for your situation, but it does address the "*Does a different mocking framework allow me to test this?*" question.

Comment: So ...the OP needs to see if there is something like `CallBase` in FakeItEasy. I'll have to check with NSub and see if there is a similar method. I expect that most mocking frameworks would be somewhat similar.

Comment: @IAbstract actually I just found that `CallBase` isn't even needed in this situation, I've cleaned up my answer as such.